# Gromov's pseudogroups and Tao's approximate groups

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gr.group-theory, riemannian-geometry, geometric-group-theory, additive-combinatorics

In his article

Gromov, M. [Almost flat manifolds](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214434488). J. Differential Geom.  13  (1978), no. 2, 231–241

Gromov exploited a notion of a *pseudogroup*.  In his book

Tao, Terence. Hilbert's fifth problem and related topics. Graduate Studies in Mathematics, 153. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2014

Tao systematically developed the notion of an *[approximate group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_group)* and gave several applications.

Both of these notions are in the subject that has come to be called geometric group theory.  Thus, Gromov builds his pseudogroup out of parts of the fundamental group with a suitable operation called Gromov product (by Buser and Karcher) which approximates composition of loops.  What is the precise relationship between the notion of pseudogroup and that of an approximate group?

Comment: One is in differential geometry and the other is in additive combinatorics -- so I am not sure there will be any relation at all.  And yet, Tao is known to take certain cues from Gromov at times (both of whom are still alive, active and occasionally appear on here).

Comment: I'm not aware of any conceptual relationship between them. Why should one exist? Hopefully not just because of the names...

Comment: Oh wow!  His [example](http://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/PDF/3%5B20%5D.pdf) of $\epsilon$-flat manifolds are nil-manifolds!

Comment: @johnmangual, that's the connection to geometric group theory, and also to his (harder) theorem on groups of polynomial growth.

Comment: it is also connection to additive number theory as the nilsequences come from nilpotent lie group. he is also discussing the word problem on rotation groups

Comment: I don't know enough about approximate groups to give a full-blown answer but I think pseudogroups (in Gromov's sense) and approximate groups are different techniques that sometimes achieve the same goals, such as the Margulis lemma and its consequences. This is explained in http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1110.5008. I think the point is that if one only cares about group theoretic conclusions (e.g. that a certain fundamental group is virtually nilpotent), then one can ignore the space where the local preudogroup acts and focus on suitable group theoretic data.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek, can you format this as an *answer*? Also, Breuillard et al don't comment on pseudogroups.

Answer (score 7):

After some thinking, I no longer believe in any deep connection between the two notions. Their definitions sound similar and can indeed be used to establish some of the same results, yet the analogy seems superficial.

Let me record some references that might help those who want to think more.

A pseudogroup seems more of a technical device similar to thinking a space as the quotient of its universal cover by the deck-transformation action.

In the collapsing theory of manifolds with two sided curvature bounds a pseudogroup is a technical device allowing to desingularise the Gromov-Hausdorff convergence. To see how it is done it is most efficient to glance through the following:

1. pp. 33-34 of Fukaya's book "Metric Riemannian geometry" https://www.math.kyoto-u.ac.jp/preprint/2004/16fukaya.pdf.
2. p.494 of Lott's paper "Dimensional reduction and the long-time behavior of Ricci flow", [https://math.berkeley.edu/~lott/2010-85-03-01.pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Elott/2010-85-03-01.pdf).

Let me informally summarize what happens in the above references: a collapsing sequence of metric balls can be (under some curvature assumptions) realized as quotients of balls in the tangent spaces by action of pseudogroups. The actions subcoverge to an isometric action of a local Lie group on some Riemannian manifold. This is a convenient way to think about local collapse developed by Gromov and Fukaya.
(There are other ways to think about collapse that do not use the language of pseudogroups.)

Thus in this construction a pseudogroup approximates a local Lie group,
whose action gives a  description of the collapse.

On the other hand, an approximate group sits, by definition, in a local group, and sometimes captures  the algebraic properties of the associated global group, such as virtual nilpotence. To see how this applies to geometric problems look at the proof of Corollaries 11.13 in Breuillard-Green-Tao's "The structure of approximate groups", https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5008. Here the geometric input is minimal (namely, the Bishop-Gromov volume comparison which gives a packing condition on the orbit of the fundamental group action in the universal cover).

The notion of an approximate group allows to decouple group theory and geometry, which is quite striking.

Answer (score 3):

Here's working definition from [What is... an Approximate Group?](http://www.ams.org/notices/201205/rtx120500655p.pdf) Let $A$ be a subset of a group with $A^{-1}=A$ then $A$ is an *$K$-approximate group* if $A^2$ is covered by a certain number $K$ of translates of $A$.

These are not even subgroups or cosets.

- Arithmetic sequences $ \{\sum n_i x_i : |n_i| < N_i \} $ is a $2^d$ approximate group.  It's not even closed under addition, it just kind of overlaps with itself.
- $S = \{\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & a & b \\ 0 & 1 & c \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) \text{ with }|a|, |c| \leq N \text{ and }|b| \leq N^2\}$ is an 100-subgroup if add it's inverses $A = S \cup S^{-1}$.

It's not hard to come up with your own definition of approximate symmetry how about:

$$ A = \{ (a,b): \mathrm{gcd}(a,b) = 1 \text{ and } |a| ,|b| \leq N \} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^2$$
and now rotate by an angle $a + bi \mapsto e^{i\theta}(a + bi)$.  This set has no intersection with itself.  Yet say the pairs of numbers $(a,b)$ which are relatively prime should be a rotationally symmetric set *approximately*  --- and this might not even fall under Tao/Green/Breullard's definition.

[image]

[The Structure of Approximate Groups](http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~breuilla/structure.pdf) outlines the types of almost-symmetry the have in mind:

> A fair proportion of the subject of additive combinatorics is concerned
>   with approximate analogues of exact algebraic properties, and the extent to which they resemble those
>   algebraic properties. In this paper we are concerned with sets that are approximately closed under
>   multiplication, which we do not necessarily assume to be commutative, and more specifically with
>   approximate groups

---

In [Almost Flat Structures](http://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/PDF/3%5B20%5D.pdf) Gromov is discussing differential geometry.  A pseudogroup is

- A set $\Gamma$ with a binary operation (that only works for some pairs) $a b$
- unique identity element $e$ and unique inverse $a^{-1}$
- $(ab)c = a(bc)$ (associativity)

In fact Gromov gives examples of his pseudogroup concept

- any symmetric subset $A \subseteq S_n$ containing the identity element $e \in A$ and $A = A^{-1}$
- his "local fundamental group" example places restrictions on his fundamental group so that the product is not always defined -- and he gave this structure a name.

These are closed under multiplication (when a multiplication exists) , while Approximate groups are definitely **not** closed.  Therefore, Gromov's definition is closer to that of [groupoid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/groupoid) and there is indeed something called the [fundamental groupoid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fundamental+groupoid) whose elements are paths and not loops.

---

To conclude there is no relation, but there are a few ways out:

- [Cayley's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem) shows every abstract group $G$ can be represented as permutations of a set.  Even infinite groups like $(\mathbb{R}, +)$.
- In [Geometric Group Theory](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/EPR/kapovich_drutu.pdf) groups are thought of as fundamental groups of interesting spaces, such as trees or surfaces or 3-manifolds, or spaces which are not manifolds at all.

Comment: "These are closed under multiplication (when a multiplication exists) , while Approximate groups are definitely not closed". I am not really convinced by this argument. If you re-define the multiplication of an approximate group by saying "undefined" when the result is not in the approximate group, you transform your "closed but not defined everywhere" multiplication into a non-closed multiplication.

Comment: the definition of approximate group emphasizes   *covering by translations* eg this nilprogression $A$ of integers $\lfloor n \sqrt{2} \lfloor n \sqrt{3} \rfloor\rfloor $ for $-N < n < N$ is a 100-approximate subgroup since $A+A$ can be covered by 100 translates $A+ b$ for various integers $b$ - you are certainly welcome to show (or fail to show) that Gromov's definition and Breullard's are the same. I will not do so here.

Comment: Neither will I. I have no issue with your main point that the two notions are not related in an interesting way. In fact, Gromov's notion seems to me a very general, rather uninteresting, concept (which is not to say, of course, that Gromov doesn't do extremely interesting things with it). If you take any set $S$ with a marked point $e$, you can make it a pseudo-group in the sense of the definition you gave by defining $ae = ea =a$ and $a^2=e$ for any $a \in S$ and leaving all the other multiplications undefined. Clearly, this pseudo-group structure has no interest whatsoever.

Comment: yes now you get it. Gromov clearly had something in mind but his definition doesn't capture any essense. Another problem is that Tao-Green-Breullard require an ancient group.  an approximate group lives inside another group (integers, permutations, matrices, etc). Gromov's definition is intrinsic. Any set with a sometimes-working binary operation will do, such as a collection of paths satisfying some length constraint. These can be embedded into the original fundamental group, maybe.

Comment: I think you may be underestimating the relation between the two notions.

Comment: @mikhail based on what? Do you see a meaningful relation between them?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Igor Belegradek's comment below my answer is a good illustration of what I have in mind.